# Overheating on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, graphics-card

I have a Dell Inspiron Q17R with two graphic cards and I noticed that it is overheating. I installed [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/), [Jupiter](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/jupiter-light-weight-power-and-hardware-control-applet.html) and [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/), and I followed [this guide](http://techhamlet.com/2012/05/ubuntu-how-to-fix-over-heating-of-laptops-with-switchable-graphics/) as well, but it still got up to 74C.

Is there anything more I can do? It still doesn't really seem to be working well and the fan keeps spinning really fast.

---

After performing the following test:

```
sensors
```

in the terminal, this is what I got:

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +75.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +75.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +68.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +68.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +65.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

it doesn't look good.

Comment: Laptops normally don't have much room for heat to escape, the best you can do is use less intensive software if you want to keep it from heating up so much, or if you want to go overkill make  a custom case fort he hardware.

Comment: Didn't really understand the second part :P

Comment: @mati Have you cleaned the insides of the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, those temperatures are not that high, compare each value to the critical (`crit` and `high`). Modern systems often run at temperatures much higher than what you may be used to.

That said there are a few things you can try:

1. Clean the laptop. At least try and clean the air intake and output grilles.
2. Make sure the fan is switching on correctly. There are some dell-specific utilities for this, install [`i8kutils`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=i8kutils):

   > This is a collection of utilities to control Dell Inspiron and Latitude laptops. It includes programs to turn the fan on and off, to read fan status, CPU temperature, BIOS version and to handle the volume buttons and Fn-keys.
   >
   > The package includes also a small Tk applet, designed to be swallowed in the GNOME panel, which monitors the CPU temperature and controls automatically the fans accordingly to user defined thresholds.
   >
   > The programs require the kernel module i8k.o which can be compiled from the package sources or found in Linux kernel 2.4.14 and later versions. The kernel module has been tested only on Inspiron 8000 laptops but it should work on any Inspiron and Latitude laptops.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install i8kutils
   ```

   You can then use `i8kfan` to test your fan. There also used to be a thing called `dellfand` but I can't find it anymore.
3. Play with the different CPU [governors](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt). The governor is what controls the current clock speed of the CPU, if you have it set to, for example, `performance`, the CPU will always run at its highest speed and so will be hot.Try setting the governor to `ondemand`:

   ```
   sudo -i
   echo ondemand > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
   ```

   You can check which governor is set with this command:

   ```
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
   ```

   Available options are:

   - performance
   - powersave
   - userspace
   - ondemand
   - conservative